# Want to get the name of the collection i am accessing,

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I am programming a adminpanel with charts etc. Now I want to access a collection but before i can do that I need to know the name of the collection. So I can use that in the method itself

this is the snippet

```html
{
  "335": [],
  "338": [
      {
        "id": 114,
        "uuid": "",
        "creator": null,
        "ip": "",
        "version": 338,
        "time": "1526806163720"
      },
      {
        "id": 115,
        "uuid": "",
        "creator": null,
        "ip": "",
        "version": 338,
        "time": "1526806269412"
      }
          ],
  "340": [],
  "389": [],
  "393": [],
  "401": [],
  "404": []
}
```

As you can see every collection that is in this collection has a name.

When I am using this piece of code it doesnt give me a way to get to the name to use it in the switch statement.

```html
        foreach ($toConvert as $convert) {
            switch ($convert) {
```

Does anyone know if this can be done or is this a limitation of laravel 5.7?

Comment: What is the name? 338, 340, ...?

Comment: Yes the 355, 338 etc are the names of the collections I am trying to get access to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
foreach ($toConvert as $name => $convert) {
    switch ($name) {
     ...
```

> The second form will additionally assign the current element's key to the $key variable on each iteration.

You can read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it was this easy!

Comment: No problem @HeroOnSocks .. if it works for you, you can mark the answer as accepted to help others with the same question.